# Convert float to float and truncate after two decimal places Objective-C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, floating, cgfloat

I have a float var1 = cashInHandAmount = 4.73000002
I simply want as:
var2 = 4.73.

I have tried like this:

```
NSString *floatString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.02f",cashInHandAmount];//it prints 4.73
[self.editcash setMaxValue:[floatString floatValue]];//but it again sets 4.73000002 why?
```

can you guys please help me regarding this?

Comment: You need an NSNumberFormatter... or better use NSDecimalNumber since what you see is the normal inaccuracy of float storage... you don't have an unlimited number of bits and thus can only represent a limited number of decimals

Comment: i have tried with NSNumberFormatter, the problem arises when get number from string, convert this number to float.This converted float number shows 8 digits after decimal place

Comment: floats will always show 8 decimals... use NSDecimalNumber

Comment: What Every Programmer Should know about Floats: http://floating-point-gui.de

Answer (score 3):

%f simply rounds for the output. Transforming a float value into a string and back does not work, if the exact value (i. e. 4.73) has no representation in the float format. So transforming it back will "round" the stored value 4.73 into the float format, which is obviously 4.730…02.

You should rarely use (binary, IEEE) floats for financial calculating. Financial values (amount of money) is in most cases an integral value of cents, but no float value of dollars (or whatever). Additionally you can think about using `NSDecimal` and `NSDecimalNumber` to ensure, that every value with two digits of precision is storable in the format.

Edit:

```
float f = 4.73000002;
float rounded = roundf(f * 100.0f) / 100.0f;
NSLog(@"%10.10f", rounded);
```

outputs:

2014-07-01 10:25:48.653 xctest[596:303] 4.7300000191

It is difficult to check, but probably float can not represent 4.73 exactly. The nearest representable value is 4.7300000191. This is what I said: A rounded decimal representation is not always a possible "binary float" representation. You will face that problem with many values.

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
    float var1 = 4.73000002;
    NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
    formatter.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle;
    formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 2;  //Set number of fractional digits

    NSNumber *num = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:var1];

    NSString *roundedNum = [formatter stringFromNumber:num];

    DLOG(@"Answer : %@", roundedNum);
```

Comment: satish thannks for theanswer, from roundedNum get float variable ? it will again produce 4.7300000....

Comment: what result u r expecting and in which data type? A variable
a float variable like float value = 0.0  always results the float value upto 6 decimal places by default like 0.000000

Answer (score 1):

If you want truncate all other decimals you can declare a simple method like this:

```
- (float)sanitizeFloat:(float)value
{
    float newValue = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f",value] floatValue];
    return newValue;
}
```

and then

```
float aFloat = 45.070809;
NSLog(@"%f",[self sanitizeFloat:aFloat]);
```

In your case:

```
[self.editcash setMaxValue:[self sanitizeFloat:cashInHandAmount]];
```

The output will be `45.070000`

Answer (score 0):

If you're working with monetary amounts that have fixed decimal places, you should always use `NSDecimal` or `NSDecimalNumber` - you shouldn't use floats at all, as they are inexact.

You could use:

```
-[NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:]
```

to create your number, and there are many methods for working with `NSDecimalNumbers` - see [Apple's docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/classes/nsdecimalnumber_class/reference/reference.html) or `NSDecimalNumber.h` for details.

Comment: They are not inexact, but simply rounded to their internal binary representation.